# How to apply background color on each listbox item from string array in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am working on an application in which I have a listbox containing 3-4 items.I want to apply background color from a string array containing colors values. Can anyone suggest how can I apply the colors from an array. I did some research and found that System.Drawing helps in c# but its not available in wp8. My listbox xaml code is as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="SampleList"
                     Margin="0,10,0,0"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GenericListBoxContainerStyle}"
                     toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                      >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2">
                        <Grid Margin="0,2,0,2"
          toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                            <StackPanel 
                    Margin="0,8,0,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"
                       Margin="10"
                       Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentStyle}"
                       Foreground="White"
                       FontFamily="/Fonts/lte50331.ttf#Frutiger LT 55 Roman"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and c# code just contains adding value of list object to item source

```
SampleList.ItemSource=list
```

and string array containing colors

```
string[] colors={hex_value1,hex_value2,hex_value3}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach item in list , add :

```
public string Color { get; set; }
```

set item.Color = each your color ;

in your xaml , add :

```
Background="{Binding Color}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Colors array to the list then bind  it to the border background.

```
 public class item()
       {
       private string name;
       private string background;
       public string Name
     {
    get
     {
    return this.name;
     }
    set 
    {
    this.name= value;
   }
  }
   public string BackgroundColor
   {
   get
   {
    return this.background;
   }
   set 
   {
    this.background= value;
}
}
  List<item> Itemlist= new List<item>()
      for(int i=0;i<Itemlist.Count;i++)
          {
     Itemlist[i].BackgroundColor=Colorsarray[i];
         }
   SampleList.ItemSource=Itemlist;

    In xaml 

    Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}"
```

Comment: can you edit in my code and explain me, or with any sample code??

Comment: This is the sample one it is not executed may have minor syntax errors